# Mongoose: reference between models with same schema keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

As a front-end developer, I would like to have some `isomorphic` object for two `mongoose` models.

Let's say I have a **user** profile:

```
const profileSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },

  // example of difference between model schemas
  __user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
}
```

And I would like to create a list of `Contact`, where each contact will have some of the same keys:

```
const contactSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },

  __profile: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Profiles',
    unique: true,
  },

  comment: { type: String }, 
}
```

***NOTE:*** `Contact` could be the both:

- as a **reference** to the `Profile`
- and as **independent** record in DB / `document`.

==============================

My question: which is the best way to, organize models on such a way, so

- contact could be a reference to the profile
- when similar `Profile` key, like `firstName` will be updated, contact `firstName` will be updated too

***AVOID of next ref***

```
await Contact.findById(SOME_ID).populate('__profile');

// result
{
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',

  __profile: {
    firstName: 'Chuck',
    lastName: 'Norris',
  }
}
```

Desired result - keep contact "isomorphic" like:

```
{
  firstName: 'Chuck', // the key value from profile
  lastName: 'Norris', // the key value from profile

  __profile: SOME_PROFILE_ID,
}
```

Is this possible?

P.S: in my app, I'm using [refs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs) and started to use [discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, complete usage of [Mongoose discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) did not give me an advantage, because discriminators give you an opportunity to:

> They enable you to have **multiple models** with overlapping schemas **on
>   top of the same** underlying MongoDB **collection**.

As a result, by using discriminators approach, I will reive one collection
 of:

- profiles

And there will be a mix of `users` and `contact` profiles.

==============================

So I decided to use two approaches:

- create [BesaSchema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator) for the profile
- take advantage of [Mongoose Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

**RESULT:**

```
// keys which are same for both user Profile and Contact
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
const util = require('util');

function BaseProfileSchema(...args) {
  Schema.apply(this, args);

  this.add({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
  });
}
util.inherits(BaseProfileSchema, Schema);

// user Profile Model
const profileSchema = new BaseProfileSchema({
  __user: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'users',
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
});

const Profile = mongoose.model('profiles', profileSchema);

// Contact with profile as subdocument
const contactProfileSchema = new BaseProfileSchema();

const contactSchema = new Schema({
  // Associations
  __refProfile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'profiles',
    index: {
      unique: true,
      sparse: true,
    },
  },
  profile: contactProfileSchema,
});

const Contact = mongoose.model('contacts', contactSchema);
```

As a result, I'm having DB with next collections:

- users
- profiles
- contacts

Both `profiles` and `contacts.profile` are IDENTICAL because I'm extending the base shared schema.

Moreover:

- inside `Contact` I'm having different keys for real referenced profile (`__refProfile` which can NOT be edit by others) and `contact.profile`
- `profile` inside connection can be edited ONLY when the contact was edited by itself

P.S: happy codding ‍

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this task either:

1) put all data inside 1 collection (e.g. Profile):

```
// Profile model
{

  firstName: 'Chuck',
  lastName: 'Norris',

  contacts: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Profile',
    unique: true,
  }],
  ...all other properties

}
```

that way you will be able to store just contacts (e.g. when I want to add just a contact) and profiles with much more info.

2) or will use discriminators to create a base class (e.g. Contact) and build Profile model upon it:

```
const options = { discriminatorKey: 'userType' };

const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  },
  options)
)

const Profile = Contact.discriminator(
  'Profile',
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      contacts: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Contact',
        unique: true,
      }],
      comments: []
    },
    options
  )
);
```

that way you will be able to save Contacts and Profiles inside 1 collection and reference base class (`Contact`) for contacts inside Profile

Hope that helps!